# Why does lshw command on ubuntu shows me ram information different from what I see on my ram when opening my laptop?

Tags: 20.04, ram, lshw

When using lshw command to verify my ram info it shows that i have:

**SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 800 MHz (1.2ns)**

But when i open my laptop I see that i have:

**2GB 1R×16 PC3L-12800S-11-13-C3**

I am using Ubuntu 20.04
The ram vendor is Samsung

When googling i found that ddr3 is the same as pc3 and ddr3l is like pc3

[free -h output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugnKk.png)

[sudo lshw -C memory output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9R27.png)

The other slot contains hynix ram stick which shows me also the same thing (DDR3)

I hope the screenshots are visible

[the ram stick on my laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWoe8.jpg)

The laptop is lenovo G50-45

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema the post has been edited

Comment: It shows that you have 4G RAM total. That's two 2G SODIMMs. What part doesn't look correct to you?

Comment: @heynnema i just added a picture of the ram..As you can see the ram is PC3L..that is the part I don't really understand

Comment: DDR3 or PC3 is the Standard Voltage memory module that operates at 1.50V (JEDEC compliant). DDR3L or PC3L is the Low Voltage memory module that operates at 1.35V (JEDEC compliant).

Comment: See https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/lenovo/lenovo-g50-45

Comment: @heynnema But why does it shows me different ram information? Or do i have a ddr3 ram or ddr3l ram? Because on the picture of the ram stick, it is a ddr3l but the command tells me that i have a ddr3

Comment: They look the same to `lshw`. The only difference, in most cases, is the operational voltage. Technically your computer uses the L variant.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you...i think so because the dmidecode -t memory command shows me also that it is a ddr3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Lenovo G50-45**

DDR3 or PC3 is the Standard Voltage memory module that operates at 1.50V (JEDEC compliant).

DDR3L or PC3L is the Low Voltage memory module that operates at 1.35V (JEDEC compliant).

These look the same to `lshw`. The only difference, in most cases, is the operational voltage.

`sudo lshw -C memory` shows that you have 4G RAM total. That's two 2G DDR3L or PC3L SODIMMs.

Technically your computer uses the L variant.

Compatible RAM upgrades: https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/lenovo/lenovo-g50-45